# How to make a dialog in IOS which allows jumping directly to Settings screen

Tags: ios, api, user-interface, settings

In my application I want to create a dialog which has a button to jump directly to the IOS Settings page. I think this was possible in 5.0 but it seems that Apple has removed this functionality. Is there is a new set of APIs which allow this in 5.1+?

The old way to do this is described in this link, but I think this is not supported in 5.1+

http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-using-url-schemes-to-open-the-settings-app-to-a-specific-page-in-ios-5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really removed in iOS 5.1, and there's no URL scheme registered for the Settings app, then it's not possible using official APIs. However, if using non-official APIs is an option, then you can use the SpringBoardServices framework:

```
int SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFStringRef displayIdentifier, Boolean suspended);
```

is a function dedicated to open applications. You can use it like this:

```
SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.preferences"), false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I know this is the case. I know people have reported this as a bug. The old version of the app I'm building relied on this!